# Expressão regular em Javascript não funciona dentro da tag form

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function celular(){var celular=document.getElementById("celular").value;
var ExpReg = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
if(ExpReg.test(celular)){
alert("Sim passou no teste.");
return true;
}
alert("Não passou no teste.");
return false;}

funciona:<input type="text" id="celular" onkeyup="celular();">
não funciona:<form><input type="text" id="celular" onkeyup="celular();"></form>
```

Comment: Cara, quando você quiser acessar a função ao submitar um form, coloque onSubmit e não onClick. Porque no onClick ele executa a função, mas vai recarregar a tela, entendeu ?
Mais uma coisa, o título da sua pergunta ta muito vago. Tenta especificar mais a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que seu intuito era verifica o campo antes do formulário ser enviado.

Note que você esta trabalhando com [eventos](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp). Eventos se relacionam com quem o disparou.

Neste caso esta correta a utilização do `onkeyup` no input, pois ele esta disparando o evento a cada vez que "um telha volta" de uma inserção.

Mas ele nada tem a haver com o envio de `form` para isso é necessário utilizar outro evento o `onsubmit`.

Lembrando que ele se relaciona ao elemento que o disparou, desta forma não seria possível usar o evento do input no form, pois o `this` deveria se o do `input` e não do `form`.

Nesse seu caso basta fazer:

```js
function _celular(){
    var celular = document.getElementById("celular").value;
    var ExpReg = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
    if (ExpReg.test(celular)) {
        alert("Sim passou no teste.");
        return true;
    }
    alert("Não passou no teste.");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="_celular()">
  <input type="text" id="celular" onkeyup="_celular()">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Pois você não usa nenhum `tris` mas sim uma busca por elemento.

Comment: Ainda não tenho pontuação para comentar respostas. Apenas complementando o que @Guilherme disse anteriormente, o evento que está procurando é `onchange`. O evento `onkeyup` é ativado sempre que você solta uma tecla do teclado, mas você quer checar apenas depois que o usuário digitou todo o número, correto? Ou, se preferir, quando a pessoa clicar no botão ENVIAR, use a propriedade de evento `onclick`: `<input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="_celular()">`

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim:

```
  // não use o mesmo nome da função, na variavel 
  // ex: var celular=document.getElementById("celular").value; 
  // function celular() {...}

  var minhasRegex = {
    telefone: /^((\+55)?([1-9]{2})([\d]{8}))$/,
    celular: /^(\+55)?([1-9]{2})([\d]{8,9})$/,
  };

function validaCelular(evento) {
  var texto = evento.target.value;

  if (minhasRegex.celular.test(texto)) {
    alert('Sim passou no teste.');
    return true;
  }
  alert('Não passou no teste.');
  return false;
};

var celularInput = document.getElementById('celular');

// Ou valida quando usuario tirar o foco do elemento
celularInput.addEventListener('blur', validaCelular);

// OU valida a cada keyup: 
celularInput.addEventListener('keyup', validaCelular);
```